# Does the "," have any role to play in the code snippet written below???Will the code produce a compiler error?

Tags: objective-c, c

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1, 2;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

What does the comma mean here and is this legal Objective-C or C? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it is legal and comma or "," is an operator...you could try referring the operator table for details...

Comment: It's legal to use `i = 1, 2` in code, but doesn't work on declaration. What are you trying to do, anyway?

Comment: @phoenix - Wrong, comma is used for different things in different locations. When calling a function, it is used to separate parameters. In definitions, it allows you to define multiple variables.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. http://codepad.org/JD4sH3sh

Comment: Comma isn't a legal operator in an initialization expression.

Comment: @Tom Zych @Lindydancer @Chris Curt-Brown i was just trying to play around with the comma operator thinking it might vary from compiler to compiler.but yeah you guys are right...it throws an error...

Answer (score 5):

The code will produce an error, as a comma in this context will introduce a new variable definition, and `2` is not a valid name of a variable.

In other contexts the comma operator can be used to "stack up" expressions, the value of the last expression will be the value of the entire expression.

Comment: By 'stack up' the expressions do you mean the same as is done in an array???For example when we say int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: No, e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i, ++j) { .. }` is legal and will increment both i and j every iteration. `return (i++, j);` will increment i and return j.

Comment: No, a comma-operator is used in expression context, when you for some reason want to throw away the value of an expression. Typically, this expression performs some kind of side-effect. For example: `if (x > 10) i = 0, j = 1;` or `x = (++y, 20)`. The comma used when initializing an array is simply a separator.

Comment: @Lindydancer...Sorry but I did not get the 'throw away' part...could you make yourself a bit more clearer here???

Comment: @phoenix: For example: `i = a+b, 20;` Here `i` will be assigned to 20, the result of `a+b` will be thrown away (or even optimized away).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try to compile it?

It won't compile. You can't assign `i` two different values (`int i = 1,2`) or whatever what you are trying to do. The [C comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) doesn't work like that and it's a bug in your code.

An more reasonable assignment would be something like `int i = 1, s = 2`

Comment: @jonsca: you are confused - you can't use the comma operator in this context - try compiling it: http://codepad.org/adLXW5ja

Comment: @jonsca: gcc throws an error: `error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant`

Comment: @phoenix: yes, that will work - again, you should try it: http://codepad.org/jU7exnfq